# Variable not being consistant in excel vba macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro in excel that if a drive exists the macro saves the file to my harddrive and thumbdrive.  If it doesn't exist, it saves to the harddrive.  When the macro runs I am getting an error.  Here is the macro:

```
Sub SaveFile()

Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject
Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject

Dim filepath As String

name = "Siemens"
filepath = "F:\Dave backup\Open Orders\Label Manifests\Active  Labels Manifest\Manifest Related\File saving testing folder\" & name & "\" & name & " Manifest " & Format(Now, "mm-dd-yyyy")

 If fso.DriveExists("F:\") = True Then

        'ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:="C:\Users\dgray\Documents\" & name & " Manifest " & Format(Now, "mm-dd-yyyy")
        'ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:="F:\Dave backup\Open Orders\" & name & "\" & name & " Manifest " & Format(Now, "mm-dd-yyyy")
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:=filepath
    Else

         'ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:="C:\Users\dgray\Documents\" & name & " Manifest " & Format(Now, "mm-dd-yyyy")
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:="F:\Dave backup\Open Orders\Label Manifests\Active  Labels Manifest\Manifest Related\File saving testing folder\" & name & "\" & name & " Manifest " & Format(Now, "mm-dd-yyyy")


    End If

End Sub
```

Here is the error I am getting:

[image: Error Message]

I don't know if you can see but the last part of the error message says "\Siemens\8E555720.  That should also say the customer name (i.e. Siemens).  In the code I have set the customer name in the variable "name".  So why is it giving me this crazy error?  All help is appreciated.

Comment: I can't see your linked image cause domain is restricted on my end, so I don't know the error. But if what you pasted is your exact code as-is, then your Else statement is trying to save-as to drive F which it just verified is not there. Maybe you meant for the else to only save to drive C:?

Comment: See what `Debug.Print filepath` prints, fix accordingly ;-)

Comment: Add the extension to the end too.

Comment: add extension to the end of what?

Comment: To the end of the file name.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might be better:

```
Sub SaveFile()

    Const PATH_C As String = "C:\Users\dgray\Documents\"
    Const PATH_F As String = "F:\Dave backup\Open Orders\Label Manifests\" & _
        "Active Labels Manifest\Manifest Related\File saving testing folder\"

    Dim fileName As String, custName As String

    custName = "Siemens"

    fileName = custName & " Manifest " & Format(Now, "mm-dd-yyyy") & ".xlsx" 'or .xlsm

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fileName:=PATH_C & fileName 'assume C is always available

    'save to F if available
    If Len(Dir(PATH_F)) > 0 Then
        'assumes the custName folder already exists...
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fileName:=PATH_F & custName & "\" & fileName
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I will try this tomorrow and let you know how it works.  Where is it checking to see if F drive exists?

Comment: `If Len(Dir(PATH_F)) > 0` checks to see if the path defined in the constant PATH_F is a valid path: it check the whole path, not just `F:\ `

Comment: Ok.  That part doesn't work.  The folders I have listed in the code block are for testing purposes.  I will verify the filepath and let you know the results.

Comment: "That part doesn't work" - that doesn't tell me much.  What does it do *instead* of work?

Answer (score 0):

I can see the space in folder name which may cause this error.

By removing  space in the foldername this error would be fixed.

Comment: When I am using this, there is an F drive (my thumbdrive as backup). It works for other customers I use this for, but for some reason this is the only one I am having issues with.

Comment: By removing  space in the foldername this error still show up?

Comment: I can't remove the spaces.  Those are the folders on my network.

Comment: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?703121-RESOLVED-How-to-Shell-from-a-directory-with-spaces-in-path.    This will help you chr$(34)